# Mathematical Equation to diffuse compounding effect

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to create a formula in Excel that calculates the amount of extra stock a person gets when they start working more:

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6  72   Me      1289538 49.00%

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6  72   Person2 1078885 41.00%

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6  72   Person3 263156  10.00%

6 Means roughly 6 hrs per week, and we look per month, otherwise we need 52 columns. Image I work 1 month 40 hrs per week. This is the new situation:

**40** 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6  72   Me      1289538 **58.59%**

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6   72   Person2 1078885 33.29%

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6   72   Person3 263156  8.12%

My stock increases **by 9,5%.** That seems fair but here's the problem:

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6    72   Me      1289538 46.79%

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6    72   Person2 1078885 39.15%

**40** 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6   72   Person3 263156  **14.06%**

When Person3 works for 1 month 40 hrs, his stock only increases **by 4%.** This is not fair and it should be linear. I'm not sure how the mathematical equation for this is. I think it's a compounding equation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer has been given by a friend:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XBtF-1Ux6fLyHECOH2_5FXGE5R89eDoyot1MONGTcWs/edit?usp=sharing